# Declare a function inside a loop in C

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int intValue, menuSelect,Results;

    intValue = 1;

    while (intValue > 0)
        { 
            printf ("Enter a positive whole number please.\n:");

            scanf ("%d", &intValue);

            if (intValue > 0)
                {
                    printf ("Enter the number 2 to shrink the positive whole number\n:");     

                    scanf ("%d", &menuSelect);

                    if (menuSelect == 2);
                    {
                        Results = shrink (intValue);

                        printf ("Shrink of %d is %d\n",intValue,Results);
                    }
                }   
            return 0;
        }
```

I keep getting this error code

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:24:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'shrink' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  Results = shrink (intValue);
            ^
prog.c:37:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
 }
 ^
```

Any suggestions on how to declare my function called `shrink` so that it executes: should I put it outside the `main`? or possibly in the `while` loop? or under the `if`?

Comment: It's kinda usual to define it above main().  If you do it that way, you don't need a explicit declaration as well.

Comment: Also,  the `;` after the `if` statement shouldn't be there.

Comment: @MartinJames I honestly see it way more the other way, with the declaration above main and the function definitions below main. But it's mostly just style preference.

Comment: @RastaJedi Your way may *look* (matter of taste) nicer, because your code reads from coarse to fine grained, but adds the hidden danger of forgetting to add a prototype.

Comment: @tofro which is why I said '*mostly* just style preference'. I *always* use forward declarations; I like to be consistent and when you have functions defined in a separate translation unit and have the prototypes in a header, the declarations end up before main in those instances as well. But you are completely right despite it being my preference.

Comment: You are both right :) *Consistency* is the key here. As a matter of preference I put functions at the top ... and on occasion have to re-shuffle all of my functions when adding a new one "in between" in the wrong place. (Which, in fact, is always a reminder I should get into the habit of *consistently* adding prototypes.)

Comment: I was not trying to say anything is wrong ;). My habit is to add prototypes in the beginning, then function implementations, then `main()`. Pure matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

1. There is no definition or declaration of shrink function.
2. You can declare the function before main() and write the function definition anywhere in the program, but not inside another function.
3. You should not define a function inside a loop because you'll encounter errors unless you add a check before the function declaration to see if the function already exists.
4. `if (menuSelect == 2);` --> `;` is not  required in your case.

example pseudo code

```
int shrink(int x);
int main()
{
shrink(variable)
}
int shrink(int x)
{
<code>
}
```

or

```
int shrink(int x)
{
<code>
}

int main()
{
shrink(variable)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void)
{
    void function(void); // declaration
    function();

    void dummy(void) {}  // definition
    dummy();
    return 0;
}

void function(void)      // definition
{
    return;
}
```

more info : [The C Programming Language](https://archive.org/details/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition) by K&R pages [67](https://archive.org/stream/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition/The%20C%20Programming%20Language%20First%20Edition%20[UA-07]#page/n73),[70](https://archive.org/stream/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition/The%20C%20Programming%20Language%20First%20Edition%20[UA-07]#page/n77)